# Jekyll: how to compile _sites to the folder above (root)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, terminal, jekyll

The Jekyll config (`_config.yml`) comes with the following defaults (among others):

```
source:      .
destination: ./_site
```

The relevant part of my filesystem tree looks like this:

```
/website/ 
/website/jekyll/
/website/jekyll/all-jekyll-templates-etc
 /website/jekyll/_site/the-static-website-generated-by-jekyll
```

But, **I want it to look like this**

```
/website/the-static-website-generated-by-jekyll
/website/jekyll/
/website/jekyll/all-jekyll-templates-etc
```

**What didn't work:**

```
source:      .
destination: ../
```

any suggestions?

Comment: destination: ./the-static-website-generated-by-jekyll? What do you mean with "didn't work"?

Comment: @Polygnome I don't have jekyll in my root folder. I'd like it to compile to the folder up step up in the directory structure. But I don't know how to make that happen.

Comment: Something like `destination: ./the-static-website-generated-by-jekyll` ?

Comment: have you tried `destination: ../the-static-website-generated-by-jekyll`? If so, what happens if you try it?